# curl PUT command removes the reviewers from pull-request while trying to edit the description

Tags: rest, curl, bitbucket

I am using a curl PUT command to update the pull-request description. It is updating the description but removing the existing (already added) reviewers.

The curl command I am using to update the pull-request description:

```
curl -s -X PUT -u '<username>':'<password>' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v -d '{"version": 1, "description": "'"should go together"'"}' https://{bitbucket.com}/rest/api/1.0/projects/{project_key}/repos/{repo_slug}/pull-requests/{pull_request_id}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you need also to pass the reviewers in the curl command:

```
curl -s --user USER:PASS --data @- --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --request PUT BITBUCKET-SERVER/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT/repos/REPO/pull-requests/PULL-REQUEST <<EOF
{
    "version": VERSION,
    "description": "DESCRIPTION",
    "reviewers": [
        {
            "user": {
                "name": "REVIEWER-1"
            },
            "user": {
                "name": "REVIEWER-2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
EOF
```

The Bitbucket API documentation says:

> Note: the reviewers list may be updated using this resource. However
>   the author and participants list may not.